# Inconsistent behavior of toLocaleString() in different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, multiple-browsers

I am working on a project where I have to deal a lot with Date and Time. Server side technology is ASP.Net and at client side I am using jQuery and jQuery Week Calendar(a jQuery plugin).

So here is the problem described, I am receiving Data Time from server something like this `2012-11-13T04:45:00.00` in GMT format.

Now at client side, I want this Date Time to be converted to Locale Date Time Format, like whatever is could be IST, EST, PKT, etc.

To achieve this, I am using JavaScript method `toLocaleString()`. This only works fine in Chrome, in other browser it works inconsistently.

Here are its outputs in different browsers:

**Google Chrome(Works fine):**

Call:

```
new Date ("2012-11-13T04:45:00.00").toLocaleString();
```

Output:

```
Tue Nov 13 2012 10:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**Mozilla Firefox:**

Call:

```
new Date ("2012-11-13T04:45:00.00").toLocaleString();
```

Output:

```
Tuesday, November 13, 2012 4:45:00 AM
```

**Safari:**

Call:

```
new Date ("2012-11-13T04:45:00.00").toLocaleString();
```

Output:

```
Invalid Date
```

**Internet Explorer:**

Call:

```
new Date ("2012-11-13T04:45:00.00").toLocaleString();
```

Output:

```
Tuesday, November 13, 2012 4:45:00 AM
```

For now these are the browsers where I tested.

Here is the **Question**:

**I need a way to convert Data Time(having format like this `2012-11-13T04:45:00.00`) To Locale Date and Time, no matter which browser client is using.**

Comment: You might be better off using a library such as [DateJS](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString) and specifying an explicit format.

Comment: FYI, it behaves inconsistently because the output is implementation dependent (i.e. not specified): http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.5.

Comment: It helps to format date, but I need a function which detect localization setting of client side Date Time and then convert it to any format which Date constructor could accept. @DCoder

Comment: Is there any way which work same way for all browser? @FelixKling

Comment: Are you able to change the date format that you retrieve from your server ?

Comment: Yes I could do this at server side using Asp.net. @jeromesmadja

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is no.  toLocaleString can be implemented however the developers wish.  What your question implies is that Chrome outputs *the string you want*.

If you would like to output that format consistently you'll need to use a separate library - like [DateJS](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/).

To do this with DateJS will need some standard format specifiers available in core.js and some that are only available in extras.js.  The documentation has a list of [all the format specifiers](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/wiki/Format-Specifiers).

The string you want is:

```
Tue Nov 13 2012 10:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

So to get this from DateJS you'll need:

```
"D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (e)"
```

The syntax for DateJS is:

```
new Date ("2012-11-13T04:45:00.00").format("D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (e)");
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `toLocaleString()` which is outdated and implemented incorrectly ***for all web browsers***, I strongly suggest using [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) for date & time formatting.

Then to format date on the client side, all you have to do is to assign valid culture and simply call the format function:

```
Globalize.culture(theCulture);
Globalize.format( new Date(2012, 1, 20), 'd' ); // short date format
Globalize.format( new Date(2012, 1, 20), 'D' ); // long date format
```

Pretty simple, isn't it? Well, you'll have to also integrate it with your ASP.Net application, which complicates things a bit. First, you will need to reference the globalize.js the regular way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to/globalize.js"></script>
```

Then it is best to include the right culture definition, that is the one you will need to use when formatting:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="path_to/cultures/globalize.culture.<% = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString() %>.js"></script>
```

Finally you will need to set `theCulture` variable before you use it:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    var theCulture = <% = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString() %>
</script>
```

Of course the more elegant way to do it, would be to create a property or the method in the code-behind that will write down the appropriate scripts for you and then reference just the method, say:

```
public string IntegrateGlobalize(string pathToLibrary)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"");
  sb.Append(pathToLibrary);
  sb.AppendLine("/globalize.js\"></script>");
  sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"");
  sb.Append(pathToLibrary);
  sb.AppendLine("/cultures/globalize.culture.");
  sb.Append(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
  sb.AppendLine(\"></script>");
  sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
  sb.Append("var theCulture = ");
  sb.Append(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
  sb.AppendLine(";</script>");

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then all you have to do, is to reference this method in the (master?) page head:

```
<head>
  <% = IntegrateGlobalize("path_to_globalize") %>
  ...
</head>
```

#### Some issues

If you want to do it 100% correctly, you will need to enhance the Globalize culture generator to include `'g'` format switch and then use this exact switch on the client side to format date:

```
Globalize.format( new Date(2012, 1, 20), 'g' ); // default date format
```

Why is that? Because 'g' is a default date format. This is what you'll get when you simply call `DateTime`'s `ToString()` method without parameters (which will imply `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` as the only parameter...). The default format is best, it will be either short or long, or any other, but the most commonly used by people using this culture.

I said that `toLocaleString()` is wrong for all web browsers. Why is that? That's because it will use web browsers settings and not the server-side detected culture. That means, that you might have mixed cultures in the same web page. That may happen if some of your dates are formatted on the server side and some other on the client side. That's why we needed to pass (detected) culture from the server side.
BTW. If you decide to include the regional preferences dialog to your web application, the mismatch would be even more visible, as `toLocaleString()` won't follow user settings...

Comment: Heh, if you look inside of the Globalize plugin, you'll notice that it is using toLocaleString internally. I already stumbled upon this problem when all of my integer numbers started to appear with two decimal zeroes on IE (although they appear fine on Firefox).

Comment: @Martin: I believe that happens only if there are no settings (some kind of the fall back mechanism). At least that's what I remember (I read through this code). BTW. toLocaleString(langTag) will be the best way to format days [in the future](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm).

Answer (score 2):

To convert a time to a locale-specific string on the server, you can use the method [DateTime.ToLongDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring.aspx). On that page, see the note about the "current culture object" (on the server) of class [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx). Make sure that's set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this issue was never addressed by any of the answers.  The OP said:

> I am receiving Data Time from server something like this `2012-11-13T04:45:00.00` in GMT format.

GMT is not a format.  This string is in ISO 8601 extended format, without any time zone specified.  The ISO 8601 spec says that without a qualifier, this is intended to represent *local time*.   To specify GMT, you would append a `Z` to the end, or you could append an offset such as `+00:00`.

The problem is, ECMAScript (v1 - v5.1) did not honor this provision in the spec.  It actually said that should be interpreted as UTC instead of local time.  Some browsers honored the ISO spec, some honored the ECMA spec.  This has been corrected for version 6, and most browsers have complied.

So - if you intend to transmit UTC/GMT based timestamps, then on the server side, you should always send a `Z` so there is no ambiguity.

Still, even if the *value* is correctly interpreted, there's no guarantee that the strings will be formatted the same across browsers.  For that, you do indeed need a library.  I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), but there are others.