# javascript toLocalestring() number precision in ie9 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 Number(val).toLocaleString("en-US")
```

this works fine in chrome and ie edge, but in ie 9 toLocaleString() fixes numbers to 2 precision.

for ex. 65565.656.toLocaleString("en-US"); -> 65,565.67

Comment: There are several duplicates to this question. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428678/inconsistent-behavior-of-tolocalestring-in-different-browser) or [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157762/tolocalestring-not-supported-in-all-browsers)

Comment: I have changed toLocaleString with custom formating, using regex

@vlzvl thanks