# Number().toLocaleString() has different format in different browsers

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I format a float to a locale string (Euro) and there are very different results in every browser. Is it possible to fix without an own function?

```
var sum=2282.0000;
var formated_sum = Number(sum.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString("de-DE", {style: "currency", currency: "EUR"});
```

Firefox result: 2.282,00 €

Chrome result: 2.282 €

IE result: 2.282,00 €

Safari result: 2282 €

Safari results are very much wrong, chrome results are not so much bad.
Any Idea how to fix that without writing an own function for formatting?

---

This question may already have an answer here:
Inconsistent behavior of toLocaleString() in different browser 
No, my question is different because i am searching for a solution for Currency, not DATE

Comment: You can try http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: There is no correct way for browsers to implement toLocaleString, hence the difference in results. But still you don't have to write your own function, just use a library like DateJS

Comment: [Here's the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.3) which essentially says it's up to the browser, so you'll need your own function if you want consistent results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent behavior of toLocaleString() in different browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428678/inconsistent-behavior-of-tolocalestring-in-different-browser)

Answer (score 4):

[ECMA 262](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.3) specifies that the function is implementation dependent and takes no arguments.

> Produces a String value that represents this Number value formatted
> according to the conventions of the host environment’s current locale.
> This function is implementation-dependent, and it is permissible, but
> not encouraged, for it to return the same thing as toString.
>
> NOTE The first parameter to this function is likely to be used in a
> future version of this standard; it is recommended that
> implementations do not use this parameter position for anything else.

It is also in [ECMA internationalization API specification](https://402.ecma-international.org/1.0/#sec-13.2.1) (which for `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` supersedes ECMA 262 but accepts 2 arguments)

> This definition supersedes the definition provided in ES5, 15.7.4.3.
>
> When the toLocaleString method is called with optional arguments
> locales and options, the following steps are taken:
>
> Let x be this Number value (as defined in ES5, 15.7.4). If locales is
> not provided, then let locales be undefined. If options is not
> provided, then let options be undefined. Let numberFormat be the
> result of creating a new object as if by the expression new
> Intl.NumberFormat(locales, options) where Intl.NumberFormat is the
> standard built-in constructor defined in 11.1.3. Return the result of
> calling the FormatNumber abstract operation (defined in 11.3.2) with
> arguments numberFormat and x. The value of the length property of the
> toLocaleString method is 0.

Besides, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) specifies that Safari has no support for it.

As for a viable solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings) on SO