# Differences in currency formatting using Number.toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, unicode, localization, currency, icu

I've been looking into locale aware number formatting for javascript and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233919/448591) that `Number.toLocaleString` and by [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942576/448591) [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) appear to be good solutions for this problem.

In particular I'd prefer building on top of already implemented abstractions for locale specific formatting rather than reinventing the wheel and coming up with one more solution to an already solved problem.

---

So I've called `Number.toLocaleString` on some different javascript environments and found that currency formatting seems to have changed:

```
(5).toLocaleString('fr-CH', {currency: 'CHF', style: 'currency'});
// Node v10.15.1:  'CHF 5.00'
// Node v12.1.0:   '5.00 CHF'
// Firefox 66.0.2: '5.00 CHF'
// Chrome 73.0.…:  '5.00 CHF'
// Safari 12.0.3:  '5.00 CHF'
// IE 11:          '5.00 fr.'
```

- IE 11 is different than the rest, but it doesn't surprise me given its age.
- What surprises me is that the formatting for `CHF` in `fr-CH` seems to have changed between node versions `10` and `12`.
- For comparison I had a look at the glibc LC_MONETARY settings for [fr_CH](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/fr_CH/) and found that it seems to place the `CHF` before the amount at least about 1997. This makes it particularly confusing that the position of `CHF` seems to be different for most current browsers.

---

I would like to know and understand:

1. Why are the positions of the `CHF` different in these cases?

   - I know that this can depend on the available system locales or the browser. But the change between node versions seems to indicate a more recent and voluntary change to me.
2. Is there a correct way to place the `CHF` or are both choices acceptable for CH, or more specifically `fr-CH`?

   - For this it would be beautiful to have an actual source like a paper or research database rather than hearsay or anecdotes.

---

### Update (2019-05-16):

In reaction to my partial [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161892/448591) I'd like to specify:

- The formatting decision for `fr_CH` is given as `currencyFormat{"#,##0.00 ¤ ;-#,##0.00 ¤"}` in commit [3bfe134](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/commit/3bfe134a860f070703200e5e305352d5af128b05) but I'm still missing a source for the decision and would love to know about it.

Comment: I've been digging trough v8 and icu sources and think I found where next to look. I'll update the question soon with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've checked out the [v8 source](https://github.com/v8/v8) to see if I can find where the behavior of `Number.toLocaleString` is defined.

- In `builtins-number.cc` I found the `BUILTIN(NumberPrototypeToLocaleString){…}` which uses `Intl::NumberToLocaleString(…)`.
- This led me to `intl-objects.cc` which implements the `Intl::NumberToLocaleString` using an `icu::number::LocalizedNumberFormatter`.

Since v8 uses [icu](http://icu-project.org) I checked out the [source](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu) to continue my search.

- My first tries to find the source of the number formatting led me to look at `decimfmt` and `numfmt` first, but I somehow kept loosing the trace.
- Then it dawned on me that it would likely make sense to keep the format definitions somewhat separate from the rest of the code. By looking around the website and the source more I finally found `icu4c/source/data/locales/de_CH.txt` and `icu4c/source/data/locales/fr_CH.txt`.

  - `de_CH.txt` has `currencyFormat{"¤ #,##0.00;¤-#,##0.00"}`.
  - `fr_CH.txt` has `currencyFormat{"#,##0.00 ¤ ;-#,##0.00 ¤"}`.
- Now using `git` I found the commit that first introduced the `currencyFormat` for `fr_CH` ([3bfe134](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/commit/3bfe134a860f070703200e5e305352d5af128b05)) 19 months ago.

  - This is plausible to be between node `v10` and `v12`.
  - I can also see that it it would make sense to fallback on `de_CH` before the `curreencyFormat` was added to `fr_CH` and therefore see that the format would change the way it did.

The commit mentions CLDR 32 alpha, and I found the [CLDR charts version 32](https://unicode.org/cldr/charts/32/).
However I'm currently not able to figure out where the chart is located that defines the `currencyFormat` for `fr_CH`.

I feel that by finding the change to the `fr_CH` `currencyFormat` I found and understand the change that leads to the change of behavior between different node versions.

As of now I don't understand why `glibc` and `icu` have differences here, but that is something I can ask around in the context of the specific projects for.

I'm under the impression that I'm still missing the specific decision or data-point which led to the `currencyFormat` implementation - if I find it I shall add it here and be satisfied.

### Update 2019-05-18:

- The CLDR 32 data can be fond in the download section under [cldr.unicode.org](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-32).

  - From [there](https://unicode.org/Public/cldr/32/) I could download the `cldr-common-32.zip` which included the file `common/main/fr_CH.xml` in which the currency format is defined like this:

```xml
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
  <currencyFormatLength>
    <currencyFormat type="standard">
      <pattern draft="contributed">#,##0.00 ¤ ;-#,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
    </currencyFormat>
  </currencyFormatLength>
</currencyFormats>
```

- Via [cldr.unicode.org](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/survey-tool) I also found the survey-tool which is used to decide on these matters and to document the outcomes of such decisions.

  - In the [Number Formatting section for fr_CH](https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/fr_CH/Number_Formatting_Patterns/24a93b3d14ba17b2) I could then see the decisions source:

[image: Screenshot of number formatting decisions for fr_CH]

### Update 2019-05-21:

So out of curiosity I've asked about this on the [libc-locales](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-locales/2019-q2/msg00050.html) list as well as on the [closest ticket](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-11555) I could find on the unicode-org ticket system.

This prompted me to investigate further and when researching this with a friend we stumbled upon the [cldr repo](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr) on Github which is focused on CLDR data rather than having CLDR related data in it like icu has.

We found that commit [c5e7787](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/commit/c5e77874db4297362adf3ebcc485b3c90199386e) introduced the first change that led to the `CHF` being placed after the number rather than before it and trough that commit became better aware of two tickets.
These tickets are [CLDR-9370](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-9370) and [CLDR-10755](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-10755), the second of which is a follow up that clears up some formatting.

While on the surface CLDR-9370 seems to mostly discuss the decimal separator, the currency symbol placement is discussed as well.

One of the sources given is a [typography guide (pdf)](https://translation-council-support-group.web.cern.ch/sites/translation-council-support-group.web.cern.ch/files/Guide%20Typo_FR_styleCERN.pdf) published by the CERN which gives detailed instructions on the ways to write numbers.

For `CHF` the guide notes:
[image: Screenshot from the CERNs typography guide, the section on writing sums of money]

Using google translate this translates to:

> Writing sums of money
>
> The number is written in three-digit increments separated by a
>   non-breaking space (no point or apostrophe of separation), and is
>   followed (and never preceded) by the indication of the currency is
>   long or abbreviated. For name abbreviations currency, we use the ISO
>   code.

Comment: Thanks for the sleuthing work! Bookmarked this, in case (unlikely) that I need to go down that rabbit hole myself.