# Javascript - UTC date to local date

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, timezone, utc

I have the following snippet:

```
var d = new Date('2015-11-23T17:44:59');
var n = d.toLocaleString();
return n;
```

On chrome looks good:

```
11/23/2015, 6:44:59 PM
```

But on safari looks good:

```
23 November 2015 at 18:44:59 GMT+1
```

On Firefox even worse:(Showed in UTC)

```
11/23/2015, 5:44:59 PM
```

Only Chrome works properly.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428678/inconsistent-behavior-of-tolocalestring-in-different-browser

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33880213/634824) I just added to the dup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you would like to output that format consistently you'll need to use a separate library - like DateJS.