# How to get system "ShortDateFormat" in javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, windows

[image]

as specified in image i need ShortDateFormat in JavaScript or Typescript. For example if system date is "27-Oct-22" then my output should be "dd-MMM-yy".

I searched a lot but no result.

Comment: Post is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210058/javascript-get-system-short-date-format ; Long story short, you can't get regional settings using JS

Comment: hi @KZander, mentioned post also didn't help me out. coz toLocaleString() is returning me date in "10/27/2022" where as my system date is in "27-Oct-2022". as seen in image.

Comment: Yes, that is because toLocaleString() is inconsistent depending on which browser you are using. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428678/inconsistent-behavior-of-tolocalestring-in-different-browser for that in particular. I would recommend you use the library DateJS